# How to align cell text to left with \makecell

Tags: tables, makecell, cell

I am using `\makecell` in table text because I need to make multiple lines text inside the cell. But I can not get the third column cells to be aligned to left. My tabular only centers the last cell. Can you figure our why?

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array, makecell} 
\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\author{First Author}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{First University}
  \city{City}
  \state{Country}
}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract here.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\section{Section}
\begin{table}[!tp]
  \caption{caption here}
  \label{table:simple}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}lllc@{}}
    \toprule
    Col 1               & Col2                      & Col 3                 & Col 4 \\
    \midrule
    Test here           &  AAA                      & DDDDDDDDD                 &GG     \\
    Test here           &  \makecell{BBB \\ CCC}    & \makecell{EEEEEE \\ FFFFFFF}  &HH     \\ 
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the `makecell` package documentation:

> This macro allows optional alignment settings. `\makecell[<vertical
>   or/and horizontal alignment>]{<cell text>}` For  vertical 
>   alignment  you  use `t` , `b` ,  or `c` —this  letters  you  usually  put 
>   in  optional  argument  of `tabular` or `array` environments.   For 
>   horizontal  alignment you may use alignment settings like `r` , `l` , or `c`
>   , or more complex, like `{p{3cm}}`[...]

---

To left-align contents in a `makecell` command, you can use the alignment option `l` as follows:
`\makecell[l]{EEEEEE \\ FFFFFFF}`

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array, makecell} 
\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\author{First Author}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{First University}
  \city{City}
  \state{Country}
}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract here.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\section{Section}
\begin{table}[!tp]
  \caption{caption here}
  \label{table:simple}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}lllc@{}}
    \toprule
    Col 1               & Col2                      & Col 3                 & Col 4 \\
    \midrule
    Test here           &  AAA                      & DDDDDDDDD                 &GG     \\
    Test here           &  \makecell{BBB \\ CCC}    & \makecell[l]{EEEEEE \\ FFFFFFF}  &HH     \\ 
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```